# Excel: Find rows where values in specific columns are in another row

Tags: excel

I have a 6-column spreadsheet in which I would like to find rows where 5 of the 6 columns match another row.

In this list, I would want all rows to be highlighted EXCEPT for 3, 6, 9, 12 and 13:

```
REC#    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6
1   D4  BE7 21677841    A   851 JERRY  NICKELL
2   D4  BE7 21677841    A   851 JERRY  NICKELL
3   D4  BE7 21677841    A   852 JOSEPH  NORTH
4   D4  BE7 21677841    A   853 JON  OGDEN
5   D4  BE7 21677841    A   853 JON  OGDEN
6   D4  BE7 21677841    A   855 GREGORY  PARRETT
7   D4  BE7 21677841    A   859 CARLA  PARTON
8   D4  BE7 21677841    A   859 CARLA  PARTON
9   D4  BE7 21677841    A   862 GERALD  PAUL
10  D4  BE7 21677841    A   866 JEREMY  PETTIT
11  D4  BE7 21677841    A   866 JEREMY  PETTIT
12  D5  BE7 21677841    A   869 COLIN  PINNER
13  D4  BE7 21677841    A   869 COLIN  PINNER
```

Using Conditional Formatting doesn't consider the 5 columns as one value, such that if one column is found anywhere else in the spreadsheet it gets highlighted.

Setting a Conditional Formatting rule of Finding Duplicates for COL1, COL2, COL3, COL5 and COL6, it correctly excluded rows 3, 6 and 9 but included 12 and 13 because COL6 matched even though COL1 didn't.

[image]

How can I find duplicates where COL1 + COL2 + COL3 + COL5 + COL6 are considered as one value?

Comment: Use a COUNTIFS()>1 formula.

Comment: Hi Scott...thanks for replying.

How does that help?  

=COUNTIFS (range1, criteria1, [range2], [criteria2], ...)

For this to work, I would have to supply the matching criteria.  That would be another row's COL1, COL2, COL3, COL5 and COL6.

=COUNTIFS(B2:D2,"=B3:D3",F2:G2,"=F3:G3") returned a #VALUE! error.  I also tried =COUNTIFS(B2:D2,"="&B3:D3,F2:G2,"="&F3:G3) only to get the same error.

Comment: `=COUTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,$C2,$D:$D,$D2,$F:$F,$F2,$G:$G,$G2)>1` Use this formula for your two applications to the ranges.

Comment: I also tried to add a new conditional format based on formula =Countifs($B$1:$D$14:$F$1:$G$14,"<1").  Got error "You may not use reference operators for Conditional Formatting criteria".

Our posts crossed each other.  Checking your suggestion now.

Comment: Hi Scott.  I applied your suggestion to Conditional Formatting based on =COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,$C2,$D:$D,$D2,$F:$F,$F2,$G:$G,$G2)>1 and the highlighting wasn't as expected...

I don't know how to post an image in this comment.

Rows 2, 5, 8 and 11-13 are not hightlighted.

Comment: see: http://imgur.com/a/9EbWt

Comment: Your applies to needs to be set to start on row 2.  If you want to use full column references for the applies to, then start the references in the formula on row 1 not row 2.

Comment: so the new formula would be `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1,$D:$D,$D1,$F:$F,$F1,$G:$G,$G1)>1` when using including the first row in the applies to

Comment: I looked at my formula again and noticed that it started at the wrong row.  Because Row 1 are the column headings, I changed it and it's highlighting correctly!  

=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,$C2,$D:$D,$D2,$F:$F,$F2,$G:$G,$G2)‌​>1 
Thanks, Scott!